# Python 3: win32 mouse_event doesn't work in time-spending tasks with GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, ctype

I'm making a simple macro, which moves cursor and click. But my macro needs some seconds to get the position which it want to move. In this case, it calls MouseEvent of win32, but cursor doesn't move or click at all.

So I tried the simlple code below.

```
def click():
    global clickPos
    time.sleep(10)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(clickPos[0], clickPos[1])
    time.sleep(0.01)
    # win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    # win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

I found it cannot execute mouse events, either. When I didn't put "time.sleep(10)" in the code block, it worked perfectly. So I think it cannot execute mouse events in time-spending tasks. What's the reason? Is it related to GUI Threads? How can I solve this problem?

p.s I tried win32api library at the first time, but I changed to use ctype hoping it can solve the problem, but I got the same result.

Comment: I fount that it works without GUI, which means it has only one main thread. Probably, I have to do something to use win32api with multi-threading.